# SVG to VectorDrawable - black areas

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, matplotlib, svg

When converting my SVG file to XML in Android Studio, some areas lose their colour and turn black. I generate the images with matplotlib.

[image]

[image: Actual result]

I would like to know what is the reason, has anyone had a similar experience?

Part of the SVG code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Created with matplotlib (https://matplotlib.org/) -->
<svg height="325.44pt" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 169.766662 325.44" width="169.766662pt" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <defs>
  <style type="text/css">
*{stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round;}
  </style>
 </defs>
 <g id="figure_1">
  <g id="patch_1">
   <path d="M 0 325.44 
L 169.766662 325.44 
L 169.766662 0 
L 0 0 
z
" style="fill:#ffffff;"/>
  </g>
  <g id="axes_1">
   <g id="patch_2">
    <path d="M 7.2 318.24 
L 7.2 7.2 
L 162.566662 7.2 
L 162.566662 318.24 
L 7.2 318.24 
" style="fill:#ffffff;"/>
   </g>
   <g id="PathCollection_1">
    <path clip-path="url(#p754b03d407)" d="M 78716.596016 -27474.520089 
L 77942.322246 -27221.279456 
L 78050.518304 -27028.327541 
L 78716.596016 -27059.341745 
L 78716.596016 -25924.398002 
L 77866.272281 -26189.452266 
L 76119.356759 -26479.331987 
L 74855.808906 -26442.999703
```

... Path continues ...

```
M -22910.24931 -17813.121791 
L -23104.077101 -18117.690382 
L -23995.151323 -17916.360593 
L -23910.337932 -17664.227519 
L -23274.708335 -17321.128788 
z
" style="fill:#ffffff;stroke:#ffffff;"/>
   </g>
   <g id="PathCollection_2">
    <defs>
     <path d="M 87.509701 -270.95066 
L 113.70849 -250.33765 
L 119.863663 -259.100553 
L 128.991691 -265.620573 
L 132.903703 -256.492545 
L 136.815715 -242.1485 
L 144.639739 -241.496498 
L 138.472461 -234.591775 
L 138.119719 -223.240442 
L 125.868684 -220.480916 
L 129.427765 -185.137266 
L 128.093109 -131.553327 
L 119.047112 -64.622833 
L 113.560196 -51.350428 
L 95.913086 -25.225786 
L 95.814223 -25.126923 
L 91.760825 -43.490791 
L 84.84039 -63.6342 
L 75.250644 -83.258577 
L 63.090452 -100.139495 
L 36.595072 -127.203339 
L 32.146221 -144.034825 
L 44.009824 -164.425393 
L 47.321746 -173.273663 
L 50.633669 -182.121934 
L 47.173451 -204.984085 
L 37.929727 -227.450783 
L 27.598506 -243.812669 
L 25.126923 -251.128557 
L 25.522376 -261.064324 
L 32.591106 -289.78413 
L 37.039957 -296.85286 
L 44.899594 -300.313077 
L 44.998457 -300.288362 
L 45.591637 -300.288362 
L 58.542737 -299.967055 
L 66.105784 -298.558253 
L 75.843825 -294.554287 
L 83.752893 -291.291796 
L 83.802325 -291.316512 
L 108.814755 -300.263646 
L 112.818721 -297.890925 
L 115.339736 -289.957141 
L 119.788587 -284.470224 
L 121.123243 -281.973925 
L 122.457898 -279.502341 
L 119.047112 -273.026791 
L 113.313037 -271.593272 
L 96.01195 -273.768266 
z
" id="mae49ba8945" style="stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:0.25;"/>
    </defs>
    <g clip-path="url(#p754b03d407)">
     <use style="fill:#000098;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:0.25;" x="0" xlink:href="#mae49ba8945" y="325.44"/>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g id="patch_3">
    <path d="M 7.2 318.24 
L 7.2 7.2 
L 162.566662 7.2 
L 162.566662 318.24 
L 7.2 318.24 
" style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-linejoin:miter;"/>
   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
 <defs>
  <clipPath id="p754b03d407">
   <rect height="311.04" width="155.366662" x="7.2" y="7.2"/>
  </clipPath>
 </defs>
</svg>
```

Android Studio complains the document contains very long lines, could that be the issue?

Comment: what page are you using to convert it?

Comment: To generate the SVG files, i am using matplotlib's save method and to convert the SVGs into vector drawables i am using Android Studio.

Comment: can you post the svg ?

Comment: The SVG path is too long to be posted but you can see the gist of it in my question already.

Comment: i am sorry,, but i don't look  the link?

Answer (score 0):

The svg to xml thing is not perfect. You can probably fix the problem by manually coloring the object. The structure of a simple image is something like

```
<vector ...>
    <path
        android:fillColor="this attribute you want to add"
        android:pathData="..." />
</vector>
```

P.S. As for the long path, you can use [avocado](https://github.com/alexjlockwood/avocado) to optimize the image.

Comment: The problem is I have hundreds of these images and cant possibly colour them myself. Some are more complex than this example so it's not a matter of simply writing a script for it either.

Comment: Try running the svgs through an optimizer like this [this](https://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-optimiser)